# Initial value problem: existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am thinking about the following initial value problem:
$$\tag{1}u'''-u^{\frac{8}{3}}u'-3u^{\frac{11}{3}}=0$$
with the initial conditions:
$$\tag{2}u(0)=u'(0)=u''(0)=1.$$
I would like to show that one can solve such initial value problem locally.

My idea is to use [Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem#Higher-order_Cauchy.E2.80.93Kowalevski_theorem):
If we let $F(t,x_1,x_2)=x_1^{\frac{8}{3}}x_2-3x_1^{\frac{11}{3}}$, then 
$F$ is analytic near $(t,x_1,x_2)=(0,1,1)$. Therefore, it follows from Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem that there exists an analytic solution $u(t)$ to $u'''=F(t,u,u')$. My question is: I wonder if my proof is correct. Another question is: since I am just seeking for smooth solution, is there another proof which gives the existence of smooth solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you proof is correct and shows the existence of a local analytic solution. You can also apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, since $u^{8/3}u'+3u^{11/3}$ is continuous as a function of $t$ and Lipschitz as a function of $u$, $u'$ and $u''$ on a neighborhood of $(t=0,u=1,u'=1,u''=1)$.